# Can't create a New Project in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio

I've recently installed Visual Studio 2015 on Windows 7. I've the problem that when I try to do File -> New -> Project and try to create a C++ Project like (Empty project/MakeFile/Win32 ecc..) and press OK, New Project windows closes and reopens again, like a loop. Someone can help me how to solve this problem?